# Obtain below Date Format in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date

From SQL Server I have to return this date format:

```
  'Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 2013'
```

Please Suggest

Comment: You can use custom date format https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx But it only supports SQL server 2012 and above.

Comment: Formatting should normally be handled by the client.

Comment: SQL server does not have an inbuilt `CAST/CONVERT` type that gives you the exact result you are looking for. You will need a combination of what @CoderofCode mentioned and string manipulation to get your result.

Comment: You can use `DATEPART` to assemble the string you want, but the timezone name (`UTC`) won't be available. The offset `+0000` will be, so you have to store and convert the timezone name yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For sql server 2012

```
SELECT concat(left(DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()),3) , ' ', 
              left(DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()),3) , ' ' ,
              DATENAME(dd, GETDATE()),' ',
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),108),
            ' UTC ',
            datepart(yyyy,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Left(DATENAME(DW,@date),3)+' '+LEFT(DATENAME(MM,@date),3)+' '+Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(DAY,@date))+' '+'00:00:00 UTC '+Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(YEAR,@date))
```